# Getting back movie ratings excluding my own

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Basically, I have a table called ratings with 3 columns `FILM`, `EMAIL`, and `RATING` in mysql.
I can get back the average rating for all the films, but I must then display the ratings
of the movies that I haven't already rated , so I must only display all the films everybody else rated except me.

```
String email = Main_Login.accounttext.getText().trim();
    statement = (PreparedStatement) con
            .prepareStatement(""
                    + "SELECT FILM,(film_total_ratings/number_of_ratings) as ratings_rating "
                    + "FROM( "
                    + "SELECT COUNT(*) as number_of_ratings, FILM, "
                    + "   SUM(RATING) as film_total_ratings "
                    + "   FROM  ratings GROUP BY film "
                    + "ORDER BY rating DESC"
                    + ") TMP_Film");
    result = (ResultSet) statement.executeQuery();

    int i = 0;
    while (result.next() && i <= 4) {

        i++;
    //  if (result.getString(1).contains(email)) {

            System.out.println((i) + ")" + " " + "[Movies You Might Like]"
                    + " " + result.getString(1) + "  " + "[Rating]" + " "
                    + result.getString(2));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to use [`CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) to add a column indicating that movie has been rated by the respective `email` or not. This is not tested but you may get the concept:

```
statement = (PreparedStatement) con
            .prepareStatement(""
                    + "SELECT FILM,(film_total_ratings/number_of_ratings) as ratings_rating "
                    + "FROM( "
                    + "SELECT COUNT(*) as number_of_ratings, FILM, "
                    + "   SUM(RATING) as film_total_ratings, "
                    + "   SUM(CASE WHEN EMAIL LIKE '%"+email+"%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as rated"
                    + "   FROM  ratings GROUP BY film HAVING rated=0 "
                    + "ORDER BY rating DESC"
                    + ") TMP_Film");
```

Comment: 'THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as rated   FROM  ratings GROUP BY film HAVING rated=0ORDER BY' at line 1 error

Comment: you need space before order by, how is it now?

Comment: may I see what is it?

Comment: near 'THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as rated   FROM  ratings GROUP BY film HAVING rated = 0 ORDER' at line 1

Comment: sorry, it's the `when` clause, try to check the update

Comment: how is it now, @user3136938?

Comment: I got the code to finaly work but nothing happened still printing my ratings

Comment: then try to add `%` in the `like` clause or please show your data sample. it would be better if you can provide your [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: Im very new to use sql i usually just use java but im trying to use a data base in my project and my last step is this so i really wouldent know what you mean by % and [sqlfiddle](sqlfiddle.com) but thank you very much for your help.

Comment: about `%`, try to see my update. `sqlfiddle` is an online tool that allows you to experiment with SQL queries.

Comment: If it doesn't print any ratings back, do you already rate every film with that `email`? if not, try to check your variable `email`'s value, what is inside? and how about the data saved in the db?

Comment: Different people rate the movies and they have there own email, and when i rate the film my email is used so i have to get all films rated except the ones that my email is in the row

Comment: Got it to work My String wasent reading in my email thank you very much for your help you realy helped me.